# Frequently updating SQLite DB and Listview (efficiency)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-contentprovider

I'm developing an application which relies on database (local) - and this database updates frequently.

What I'm trying to achieve is:
Suppose the data is shown in a listview. I want the listview to update the dataset **as soon as** any change in the database happens (or a specific table to be precise).

So far I've thought of these options:

1. SQLiteOpenHelper class: whenever an update/insert is done it'll notify the activity to update listview via BroadcastReceiver.
2. ContentProvider with CursorLoader (haven't used it before so a little skeptical)
3. Something else? Please suggest.

Which is the best way to achieve consistent and immediate updates without blocking the UI (performance)?

Comment: option no 2 is your friend

Comment: Use CursorLoader. You don't necessarily need a ContentProvider, you can write your own CursorLoader that queries your database directly instead of using a ContentResolver

Comment: Thanks! Finally settled down with custom CursorLoader. Will share the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Karakuri created a custom CursorLoader by extending CursorLoader class without ContentProvider.

Here's the solution:

CustomCursorLoader.class

```
public class CustomCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    private final ForceLoadContentObserver forceLoadContentObserver = new ForceLoadContentObserver();

    public CustomCursorLoader(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        super(context, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = /* get cursor from DBHandler class */;
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.getCount();
            cursor.registerContentObserver(forceLoadContentObserver);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Every time you make a change to DB, do:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
```

In Activity class:

implement interface `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`

initiate loader `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`

and override these methods:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CustomCursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    customCursorLoaderAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    customCursorLoaderAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

extend `CursorAdapter` class to create listview adapter and you're done.

Comment: what was the import type of your CONTENT_URI here?

Comment: Note, I had to use getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

Answer (score 0):

If performance is crucial for your app you should take a look on [Realm for Android](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) database. It provides better efficiency than SQLite and you can use `RealmChangeListener` to listen for changes in the database.